# Passing CSV file from Angular7 to MVC .Net Core

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core, file-upload, angular7

I'm trying to pass a CSV file to my backend to utilize a library for parsing CSV data.

I've got an Angular7 front end with a C# .Net Core MVC backend utilizing the HttpClient in typescript in order to pass data and objects to and from the backend.

I've tried a number of solutions but with minimal success (the closest being that I can reach the controller in my code, but the file never gets passed in).

I'm trying to avoid doing any kind of serialization or conversion of the CSV until it hits the controller so I'd like to find a solution where I can send the whole of the CSV to the backend.

Any help would be appreciated.

**service.ts**

```
// Parse CSV
// The CSV always reaches this part of the code and I can inspect it.
parseCsv$(file: File): Observable<Dto> {
    const request$ = this.http.post<Dto>(
        location.origin + '/api/csvimport',
        file,
        { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }) }
    ).pipe(
        map((response: <Dto>) => response)
    );

    request$.subscribe();

    return request$;
}
```

**CsvImportController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Dto), 200)]

    // The 'file' variable below is always null
    public async Task<IActionResult> ParseCsv([FromBody]IFormFile file)
    {
        // do work here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out,

I needed to change `File` to a `FileList` and then use `FormData` to append the file.  I also needed to drop my content header as letting the backend handle typing the content itself stopped errors from being thrown.  In my controller I had to use an `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` for this to fully work.

> I don't fully understand why I had to use a `FileList` when only
>   uploading one file, but this was required in order to send along the
>   file. If I find out more, I will update my answer.

**EDIT:** Addressing the above, in the MDN documentation, it states that *"All `<input>` element nodes have a files attribute of type `FileList` on them which allows access to the items in this list"* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) So in order to access one file, you actually need to access the first index (`FileList[0]`) of the `FileList` array. I may be misunderstanding this, so feel free to comment.

**service.ts**

```
parseCsv$(files: FileList): Observable<Dto> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    Array.from(files).forEach(
        (file: File) => formData.append(file.name, file)
    );

    return this.http.post<Dto>(
        location.origin + '/api/csvimport',
        formData)
    .pipe(
        map((response: <Dto>) => response)
    );
}
```

**CsvImportController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Dto), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ParseCsv(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
{
    // Work here...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use FromBody parameter in File Upload.

You should either use, [request.Form.Files collection](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/) to get the uploaded file, 
OR

you can use IList in the controller action as shown below.

Below API gets list of files which are then saved in the temp folder on server.

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

Hope this helps.